# How to enter special symbols with Alt in Emacs under Mac Os X?

Tags: emacs

In Mac Os X using the `alt` key with some other key will produce a series of special symbols. E.g. `alt-'` results in `æ`, `alt-3` results in `£`, etc. When using emacs, however, I can no longer input these special symbols this way since `alt` is now mapped to `meta`. Is there a way to map `alt` to some other key combo? Or maybe use the left `alt` as meta only and have the right behave as it normally does in other apps?

Comment: I removed the OSX tag because people who read that tag activity are likely to vote to close, and/or may not be familiar with Emacs.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are additional methods to obtain special characters other than the one mentioned in this answer, but I personally prefer the best of both worlds -- i.e., I use the left alt/option key as meta, and I use the right alt/option key for stock Apple stuff -- e.g., special characters like the ones mentioned by the original poster:

```lisp
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
```