# I can't type brackets on Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am new to Emacs. I use GNU Emacs 25.3 (9.0) on my Mac and have an Italian keyboard. My problem is that I cannot type round, square and curly braces. Unfortunately I could not find any solution on the Internet. I have seen here other people asked for help for a similar problem but I have not figured out how the answers they got apply in my case.

Comment: If these are special characters normally entered with the alt/option key, then one option would be to have the left alt/option key be used for Meta and the right alt/option key be used for special Mac OSX characters.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704657/2112489  If you are using Emacs in the terminal, things may be different and that is not something I am readily familiar with.