# Emacs in spanish keyboard

Tags: emacs

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't type `}` on emacs.
I don't really know if there is a difference between the defined keyboard
entry on my MacOS High Sierra, which is set in `Español-ISO` and the encoding of my Emacs buffer, which is `U:---`.

The way I usually type `}` would correspond do `M-ç` on Emacs, but
Emacs displays  `M-ç is undefined`. I thought all it would take was 
to change the emacs buffer encoding to `Español-ISO`. However, when I 
execute `M-x list-coding-systems` , I can't find (or I'm unable to identify)
this encoding.

I tried typing `}` on Vim and it just worked. It seems Im not understanding
something about Emacs or more generally about encodings and keyboard entry.
So if anyone can point me to a resource that clarifies these topics I'll be
very thankful.

So, in synthesis. 1) I don't know weather the input entry set on my
system preferences is a synonym of encoding. 2) I don't know why 
emacs keyboard entry works differently than the rest of my OS. 3)
I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: From the question, it is unclear whether you are using the GUI version of Emacs or the terminal version.  Here is a link to settings that I use in the GUI version of Emacs for OSX that gives me system OSX default behavior with the right option/alt key and Emacs behavior with the left optional/alt key:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704657/2112489  Using stackoverflow tags that are unrelated to Emacs (e.g., "encoding" and "keyboard") will attract people who are probably unfamiliar with the issue and those people are more likely to down-vote and/or vote to close questions.

Comment: @lawlist. Hi, I didn't knew the keyboard input will be different on GUI vs CLI. Im using GUI. I created my init file and added the code you linked and the mini buffer still prints `M- ç` is undefined. I know emacs is loading the init file because it added a `(package-initalize)` line automatically to the file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of @lawlist indeed works. In my case it didn't work at first because I didn't reboot the OS (or at least that's how I explain it), even though I did close emacs and fired it again and again. One day later, I turned on my macbook, fired up Emacs and the keys just worked how they where supposed to.

So if its not working for you try rebooting your pc.